# How to add placeholders to Textareas in Django

Tags: django, templates, textarea, placeholder

I have searched stack overflow, and I could not find an answer to this question. 
What I'm trying to do is add a placeholder to a `textarea` element but I don't know to accomplish this.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            'price',
            'title',
            'body',
            'contact_email',
            'contact_number',
            'picture',
        )
        widgets = {
            'price': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Price'}),
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Item for sale'}),
            'body': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Describe the item'}),
            'contact_email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Price'}),
            'contact_number': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Price'}),
        }
```

So as you can see I've set placeholders that render correctly for all of the fields except the `body` field because unlike every other field, it's a `<textarea></textarea>` element, not an `input` element.

create-post.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<!-- {% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'accounts/login.css' %}" type="text/css"> -->
<title>Create Post</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container"><br>
  <form method="POST" action='' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

[This](https://i.gyazo.com/adc074e2a0c8496be93d4410399c0d39.png) is how the form renders right now. As you can see the body is not large like it's supposed to be [here](https://i.gyazo.com/1d943ec6653574e1cbfa0a8bc9ec6ff5.png).

How can I add a placeholder to a `textarea` element so it retains its size.

Comment: You have searched SO and could find an answer. If so, why do you post a question for which you have already found an answer. Or did you maybe mean you couldn't find an answer, which sounds like you made a typo in the opening.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I have corrected the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

in widgets change `TextInput` to `Textarea`

```
'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Describe the item'})
```

I did try that already, but I was capitalizing the A in Area.

Answer (score 0):

forms.Textarea(attrs= {‘placeholder’: ‘what\’s on your mind ?’})

This will turn the box into a Textarea.

forms.TextInput(attrs= {‘placeholder’: ‘what\’s on your mind ?’})

This will make it a small box.
It all depends on what you’re working on.